# Warning C6386 - How to avoid Buffer overrun

Tags: c++, warnings

The below code raised the Buffer overrun warning message. It would be helpful if anyone identifies the issue with this code snippet.

```
int *index;
UINT tasks = 1024;

index = (int*)malloc( tasks * sizeof(int));
for (UINT ixFree = 0; ixFree < tasks; ixFree++)
    index[ixFree] = ixFree; //Warning   C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'index':  the writable size is 'tasks*sizeof(int)' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written.
```

Thanks,

Comment: With the *actual* code you've given, and using Visual Studio 2019, I don't see the same warning! Instead, I see: warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'index'. Maybe you get this in code where `tasks` is assigned a potentially different value?

Comment: But, anyway, you have tagged `C++`, so why are you using `malloc`? Just use `index = new int[tasks];` or, better still, use a `std::vector` in place of the raw pointer.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMole. I just use index = new int[tasks];. Now, the warning message goes off. I'm going to check functionalities. Thanks for your help :)